# Change general color when using \textbf{}

Tags: color

I am trying to change the color to red everytime I use the function `\textbf{}`. Is there a possible way to do it globally, i.e. when I type `\textbf{}` it changes to the desire color automatically, instead of doing it for each time I need it i.e. `\textcolor{red}{\textbf{}}`?

Comment: Why not use a `\newcommand`? Say, `\newcommand{\rtext}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}}}`.

Comment: Alternative solutions that also works in math mode: [macros - is there a way to 'breakeline' a newcommand? (to modify only \textbf color) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703387/is-there-a-way-to-breakeline-a-newcommand-to-modify-only-textbf-color)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put in preamble

```
\let\oldtextbf\textbf
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\oldtextbf{#1}}}
```

**Edit:**
With new version of LaTeX is more roust to use of `\NewCommandCopy` instead o `\let`. So an MWE as noted @campa in his comment also can be:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\NewCommandCopy\oldtextbf\textbf
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\oldtextbf{#1}}}

Let make this word \textbf{red and boldface}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, this answer is relative old and in time of writing I was not aware for existence of the `\NewCommandCopy` instruction/command. I will tested it and see how it works. Than I will consider your suggestion. Thank you very much for info.

Comment: @campa, done!   See addendum ...